# Duplicate Duplicates - What's the point?

Tags: discussion, flags

I've noticed recently that the flag options have 2 duplicate flags and was wondering what the reasoning behind that was. When you flag a question, you can either flag as a duplicate directly from the first prompt and clicking **a duplicate**, or go to **Should be closed..** and then **duplicate of...**. These two flag options seem redundant. What's the point if they do the same thing and have literally the same exact description and almost the same name?

Here are some screenshots complemented by FHCs:

[image]

The image is the flag prompt first page. The following is in **should be closed...**:

[image]

Comment: Probably since duplicate is often used it got a place on the first list, so you don't have to click twice. *Saved a click every time a question got closed as duplicated!*

Comment: But then why have the second flag option? @Rizier123 why not remove the one in **should be closed..**?

Comment: So that it is the same interface as the real close button and that if you clicked on it you don't have to go back and need another click! to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question can be **closed** as **a duplicate question** to lead as a signpost. It is more constructive than **directly closing** for the site and would becoming dead weight otherwise, as future readers who stumble upon a similar problem can follow the "This post is a duplicate of" link to find their answers.

Therefore, I assume **a secondary link** is added to encourage users to **mark as duplicate** instead of the conventional close options that puts a post on-hold and devoids it of value until it is reopened.

However, **it is still an option to vote to close** and **should remain for Close Vote reviewing**. This is what we see:

[image]

Comment: I get what you're saying, makes sense.